# Azure DevOps - users can't see Projects shared by me using their AD group

Tags: azure-devops

I add external AD groups to my Organization/Project level just fine. That is, to share my Projects with them.
But, users belonging to the AD groups don't see anything from me on their Azure DevOps home page.
Only when I add them individually as Organization 'Users', they see my projects.
Wondering if I need to do something extra to make AD Groups fully work.
Permissions are Ok. I added the groups even as 'Project Administrators'.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First，you need to check if the organization is properly connected to AAD in the following article, [Connect your organization to Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops&preserve-view=true) .

[image]

Confirm that the connection process is complete. Sign out, and then open your browser in a private session and sign in to your organization with your **Azure AD** or **work credentials**.

You can let users to go to [azure DevOps profile](https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?mkt=zh-CN&campaign=o%7Emsft%7Eold%7Evsts%7Eprofile#) page to check if they switch to the corresponding domain.

[image]

Comment: Yes Hugh, profiles have the correct domain, as you advised. Must be something else.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.